# what does mean " closing area to white settlement "?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

refrence: diplomacy VSI. Oxford
In an effort to prevent further warfare with the Indian peoples, the Proclamation of 1763 **closed** the vast trans-Appalachian area **to white settlement**.

Answer (score 3):

*White settlement* means "settlement by white people", and *closing X to Y* means forbidding X to Y.

> I closed the discussion to the public.
>
> Tokugawa Iemitsu closed Japan to Westerners.
>
> Under segregation, certain places were closed to Black people.

So in this case the area of trans-Appalachia was forbidden to be settled by white people.

Comment: does it mean that Black people forbiddened from living in area of trans-Appalachia?

Comment: The text from Oxford is slightly reductive. In fact, the proclamation forbids all of King George III's "loving Subjects from making any Purchases or Settlements whatever, or taking Possession of any of the Lands above reserved. without our especial leave and Licence for that Purpose first obtained". In other words, any subject of the king couldn't settle in trans-Appalachia by law.

Comment: reference: DIPLOMACY
https://books.google.com/books?id=i0sTiwJQMi0C&pg=PT36&lpg=PT36&dq=In+an+effort+to+prevent+further+warfare+with+the+Indian+peoples,+the+Proclamation+of+1763+closed+the+vast+trans-Appalachian+area+to+white+settlement.&source=bl&ots=0eriri7L2M&sig=fA2ITKZqfe5GJB7QUC5sl3yavc4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja0_no0tLNAhVM1xoKHdzFAFEQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=In%20an%20effort%20to%20prevent%20further%20warfare%20with%20the%20Indian%20peoples%2C%20the%20Proclamation%20of%201763%20closed%20the%20vast%20trans-Appalachian%20area%20to%20white%20settlement.&f=false

Comment: @yorgun Please include (i.e., cite) your reference in your question. It's easier for the future reader that way.